# Select query in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, web

I have a table name 'course_schedule' 
i have tried this but this is'nt worked

```
    $this->db->select('*')->from('course_assign_tutor');
    $this->db->join('courses', 'courses.course_id = course_assign_tutor.course_id');

    $get_CourseInfo = $this->db->get();

    if ($get_CourseInfo->num_rows()>0) {

        foreach ($get_CourseInfo->result_array() as $get_CourseInfoRow) {   
            $this->db->select('*')->from('course_schedule');
            $this->db->where('course_assign_tutor_id',$get_CourseInfoRow['course_assign_tutor_id']);
            $this->db->where('status',0);
            $new_course = $this->db->get();

            if ($new_course->num_rows()>0) {
                $new_courses[] = $new_course->result_array();
            }
            else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('no_new_coursess', 'There is no new courses');
            }
        }
```

In the above table i have 2 different 'course_assign_tutor_id'.
9 and 12. Has all 'status' of 'course_assign_tutor_id 9' is not equal to zero. so i want to ignore this 'course_assign_tutor_id 9' because it have one 'status=1'. Come to another 'course_assign_tutor_id = 12' which has all status is equal to zero. So i want this record.

How to make a dynamic query in code-igniter so that to get those data that have all status = 0.

Comment: Please provide the tables with some example data as text tables and expected result also as a text table... and update the question with the information

Comment: I missed the first two lines of code that seemed out of context until you edited the question. Comment deleted.